# Joomla 3 local admin redirects to live admin panel

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I want to access my Joomla 3 site in local. So I downloaded the project and add it to local xampp. now I want to access admin panel but problem is it redirects to the live site admin panel. I'v changed the live_site in configuration but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possibilities where your site redirected to the production server.

1. User plugin - The custom user plugin may cause false redirection, Please check user plugin from plugin list and try to debug it.
2. Custom component - Custom component such as Admin tool restrict the backend access if you have installed it then rename the htaccess generates by admin tool.
3. htaccess - If you are using default Joomla htaccess then try to login by renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to backup your live site using **Akeeba backup** Joomla extension and then download **'jpa' or 'zip'** file of your backup from '**Akeeba Manage**' section of your live site and then use that file in your local xampp and extract it and try it on localhost again.